# Using for loop after if /else statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

This is just a simple multiplication program using an
if /
else and
for loop.
Re - entering a positive number from a prompt and assigning it to the num variable which the
for loop should use is breaking the program.I’ m not sure why it is incorrect. ? Perhaps you could tell me the best way to do this using the
    if /
    else and
    for loop.
Any help much appreciated.

```
//Array variable and counter variable

var multi = new Array();

var Counter;

//Enter a number between 1 and 12 and hold in num variable

num = prompt("Enter a number between 1 and 12");

//Check if number is less than zero
//Reenter positive number

if (num < 0) {
    var num = prompt("Enter a number greater than zero");
} 
else {
    //Number entered by user multiplied by counter value
    for (Counter = 1; Counter <= 12; Counter++) {
        multi[Counter] = num * Counter;
    }
    //Loop to display number that is being multiplied each time 
    for (Counter = 1; Counter <= 12; Counter++) {
        document.write(Counter + " x " + num + "  = " + multi[Counter] + '<br/>');
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be `var num` instead of `num` and then `num` instead of `var num`.

Comment: And `document.write` overwrites the document

Comment: why are you using two diff loops you multiply and display in one for loop right?

Comment: `var num; do { num = prompt("Enter a number between 1 and 12"); } while (num < 1 || num > 12);`

Comment: What does *"breaking the program"* mean, what exactly doesn't work ?

Comment: Two conventions in javascript: 1) use literals instead of the Array, Object, String, or Number constructors (var arr = []; var obj = {}; etc) and 2) names with an initial capital are generally reserved for constructor functions.

Comment: much obliged  melpomene

Comment: Jared smith much obliged, I will look at this.

Answer (score 1):

This can be simplified at the same time as fixing your code.

The reason entering a negative number was causing the code to fail was because you would never hit the `else` block and so never run the intended code within it.

As suggested by melpomene a do/while loop will serve you well here.

You also don't need 2 separate `for` loops, they can be condensed into one.

```
var num;

do {

  // Enter a number between 1 and 12 and hold in num variable
  // Check if number is not between 1 and 12 and re-enter
  num = prompt("Enter a number between 1 and 12");

} while (num < 1 || num > 12);

// You can define your counter variable within the for loop
for (var counter = 1; counter <= 12; counter++) {

   document.write(counter + ' x ' + num + '  = ' + (num * counter) + '<br/>')

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Josh. I didn't realise I was never hitting the else block. I spent a lot of time on this, pitfalls of being a new programmer.

Comment: No problem - keep at it!